# svg в google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

Не могу понять почему svg так не корректно отображается на хроме, если присмотреться то на кнопочке крестик, в середине линий пустые пиксели.
Сверху правильно отображение ie11, а снизу хром

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаю в тегом img, но и через фон такая же проблема.

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" width="15.414425397698665" height="15.414002244208632" viewBox="0 0 15.414425397698665 15.414002244208632"><title>close</title><desc>Created with Avocode.</desc><defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"></defs><path id="SvgjsPath1007" d="M325.647 46.3537L326.354 45.6465L332.00347999999997 51.29603L337.597 45.7027L338.29699999999997 46.4034L332.70414 51.99669L338.354 57.6466L337.64599999999996 58.3535L331.99688 52.70399999999999L326.404 58.29729999999999L325.703 57.59629999999999L331.29621 52.00327999999999Z " fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="50" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-324.29278730115067,-44.292998877895684)"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Будьте добры, покажите svg код

Comment: @Shilgen к сожалению у меня только минимизированный, но если не разберетесь, то постараюсь как то его разобрать. Код генерировался из картинки в программе avocode. Код в топике. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что крестик залит прозрачным фоном:

```
fill-opacity="0"
```

Кроме того, можно выкинуть кучу лишних параметров из разметки.
А вообще, хочется этот крестик полностью переписать - см третий вариант...

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-size: 10em;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" width="15.414425397698665" height="15.414002244208632" viewBox="0 0 15.414425397698665 15.414002244208632"><title>close</title><desc>Created with Avocode.</desc><defs id="SvgjsDefs1001"></defs><path id="SvgjsPath1007" d="M325.647 46.3537L326.354 45.6465L332.00347999999997 51.29603L337.597 45.7027L338.29699999999997 46.4034L332.70414 51.99669L338.354 57.6466L337.64599999999996 58.3535L331.99688 52.70399999999999L326.404 58.29729999999999L325.703 57.59629999999999L331.29621 52.00327999999999Z " fill-opacity="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-miterlimit="50" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-324.29278730115067,-44.292998877895684)"></path></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 15.414425397698665 15.414002244208632"><title>close</title><path d="M325.647 46.3537L326.354 45.6465L332.00347999999997 51.29603L337.597 45.7027L338.29699999999997 46.4034L332.70414 51.99669L338.354 57.6466L337.64599999999996 58.3535L331.99688 52.70399999999999L326.404 58.29729999999999L325.703 57.59629999999999L331.29621 52.00327999999999Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-324.29278730115067,-44.292998877895684)"></path></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-8 -8 16 16"><title>close</title><path d="M -6.7 -6.7 L 6.7 6.7 M -6.7 6.7 L 6.7 -6.7" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="2"/></svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли.